# How to modify saturation and value channel on images correctly

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am currently doing some experiment to change skin color on image using python. I have encountered problem when I tried to modify saturation and value channel by subtraction or summation certain value on it. Please see this image to get what I mean

This is the result when I tried to increase the saturation while decreasing the value. Some weird black and red pixels comes out on the outline

[image: summation]

This is another result but I switched the modification to decrease the saturation while increase the value. Some images will have some red bleeding like this result

[image: subtract]

This is the code that I used to modify the images. Basically I only extract the image RGB value and change it to HSV value then directly subtract/summarize the channel by elementwise

```
for img in list_im:
    ori_image = cv2.imread(img)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(ori_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL)
    h=image[:,:,0].copy()
    hues=np.round(h/255*360)
    sat=image[:,:,1].copy()
    saturation=sat.flatten()
    val=image[:,:,2].copy()
    value=value.flatten()
    #get hue channel only
    #create bin interval (0,1),(1,2),...
    binEdges = np.arange(0,361)
    satBin = np.arange(1,255)
    valBin = np.arange(0,254)
    row,col=hues.shape
    hues= hues.reshape(row*col) 
    #experiment negrofication
    sat[sat>0]+=60
    val[val<255]-=100
    im=np.dstack((h,sat,val))
    im=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL)


    rainbow = plt.get_cmap('hsv')
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5, forward=True)
    plot = plt.scatter(binEdges, binEdges, c = binEdges, cmap = 'hsv')
    plt.clf()
    a = fig.add_subplot(5, 1, 1)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(ori_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    a.set_title('original')
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=2)
    e = fig.add_subplot(5,1,2)
    plt.imshow(im)
    e.set_title('rework')  
    plt.savefig(os.path.join('/home/cgal/color_harmonization/', 'Result_saturation', os.path.basename(img)),bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.show()
```

This is the code that I used to create the masking in case someone is wondering about it. So those jawline, eyes, and mouth are the location on the images. After I got the mask, I multiply it to the original images.

```
def getmask(img,jawline,eyes,mouth):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    imArray = np.asarray(img)
    # create mask
    polygon = jawline.flatten().tolist()
    maskIm = Image.new('L', (imArray.shape[1], imArray.shape[0]), 0)
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(polygon, fill='white')
    #ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(polygon, outline=(1))
    # draw eyes
    righteyes=eyes[0:6].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(righteyes, fill='black')
    lefteyes=eyes[6:].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(lefteyes, fill='black')
    # draw mouth
    mouth=mouth.flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm,).polygon(mouth, fill='black')

    mask = np.array(maskIm)
    return mask
```

So I was hoping to find a way to modify the saturation and value channel without any side effect of red bleeding or unexpected black pixels on outline which I have showed on the pictures above. Any new technique or suggestion to fix my code are welcomed. Thank you

Comment: Most likely, your problems come from `sat[sat>0]+=60`, `val[val<255]-=100`. You don't check for possible overflows (`sat > 255`) or underflows (`val < 0`).

Comment: I have already tried and limit in case of overflowing but the problem still persist